# Swift UITableview Header Section Constraint Problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xib

I use `Xib` file in the `viewForHeaderInSection`. There is no problem about implementation and showing the items. But I have a label in the Xib file and If the label text length is more longer than screen width size , the view is not showing correctly. You can see the images on the top that is not in the center because of label length.

Note: Label lines is "0"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let v : ProductDetailHeaderView = UIView.fromNib()
   productDetailHeaderView = v
   productDetailHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   return productDetailHeaderView
}
```

If I remove `productDetailHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` , tableview doesnt scroll correctly.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried constraining your label's leading and trailing edges to the bounds of its container?

Comment: Yes, I tried ...

Comment: That should solve it. Unless your container’s bounds are not the size you expect. Use the view debugging tool in XCode. Also look for broken constraints at run time in the execution log.

Comment: It didnt solve.

Comment: Well, it's really hard to help you any further unless you document what state your views are in, what you've tried, what didn't work and how you measured your results.

Comment: I just noticed something bizarre. What is this fromNib() constructor you're using on `ProductDetailHeaderView`? How does that view get added to your view hierarchy? As I said previously, you'll need to seriously beef up your question to get any kind of help.

Comment: I use extension to UIView -- class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }

Comment: Please update your question with this. Also, how does ProductDetailView get added to the view hierarchy? Are we missing other code that does this? If so, please also edit your question with all relevant code.

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed that you don't need to add it to the view hierarchy as it's a table view header. Then, what is the view's frame after it has been added?

Comment: Also detail the existing constraints that are present in the ProductDetailView, relative to the label